# How can I efficiently create an array of ordered uint values given a count and a starting value?

Tags: gas, arrays

I would like to create an array of uints of arbitrary length without having to iterate in a loop, as this seems like it would be costly for large arrays.

e.g. given a count of 5 and a start index of 8 I would like to construct a memory array of [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ].

The code below is the best I currently have. The function signature is just an example the important bit is how I get a populated array of "values"

```
function createArray(uint startIndex, uint count) public pure returns (uint[] memory) {
    uint[] memory values = new uint[](count); 
    for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        values[i] = i + startIndex;
    }
    //... do things with this array
    return values;
}
```

Can this be achieved in a more efficient manner?

EDIT: For additional context, I would like to batch-mint nfts on an ERC1155 contract. I don't want to have to specify the ids, just say how many I want minting (hence the count) and the contract will keep an internal value indicating the id of the last minted NFT (hence the start index).

Answer (score 0):

Try to define all elements in an array in memory, then push all elements once:

```
uint [] public myArray;
function createArray (uint startIndex, uint count) public returns(uint[] memory){
   uint[] memory newArray;

   for (uint i = 0 ; i < count+1; i++) {
      newArray[i] = startIndex + i;
   }
   myArray = newArray;
   return myArray;
}
```

Comment: `newArray` is uninitialized, so the contract will revert.

Comment: OMG thats my bad... i wrote unit instead of uint and i and also `i` needs an uint before.I'll edit it. try again

Comment: It still using `newArray` without allocating the memory, and the for condition should be `i < count`.